# Creating SKScene, init(fileNamed:) vs init(size:)

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, initialization, skscene

If you make a new game template project in Xcode, the default `GameViewController` will use the following initializer to instantiate the game scene:

```
let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")
```

The initializer's use in the template file suggests that this is Apple's recommended way for creating an `SKScene`. However, I have seen many examples on Stack Overflow that use the `init(size:)` initializer or simply `SKScene()`.

I am wondering which is the best way to create an instance of `SKScene` and what are the advantages/disadvantages of each way, as well as various pitfalls to look out for when using one approach versus another.

My reason for asking is that I used `init(fileNamed:)` to create my game's scene and build level 1. When I later tried to create another instance of the scene for level 2 using `init(size:)`, I ran into problems. Namely, some positional calculations using `UIScreen` and the scene's frame seem to produce different results if I create the scene using `init(size:)` instead of `init(fileNamed:)`.

In a more general sense, I would like to hear the opinion of someone who is very familiar with using iOS and SpriteKit about their preferred way of initializing a new `SKScene` and the pros & cons of using different approaches.

Comment: I don't have a full answer but I used the fileNamed overload and it was ok, I then cached the scenes for easy navigation

Comment: Part of the issue might be that init(size:) will initialize with different default values than you expect compared to scenes you load from a file using init(fileNamed:).  For instance, your scene size will differ based on what you pass in.  Your scene will have a different name.  It might be a different subclass of SKScene.  Its anchorPoint may not be in the same place.  Etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I very strongly recommend not using `init(size:)` when it comes to creating your scenes that you use as a part of your game.  You really should try to keep design separate from structure.  This allows for you to change how the layout of your game is, without changing any code, thus reducing the potential for bugs.

With that being said, there is a very common practice tutorials use that looks like this `init(size:view.size)`.  This one causes all kinds of trouble with game designers, and destroys the simple handling of multiple devices that SpriteKit offers.  People tend to end up in a 0..1 coordinate system, placing divides everywhere when positioning their nodes, and this too leads to bugs because people may end up forgetting a divide somewhere, or using width when they meant height.

SKScenes have 4 scale modes that handle how a scene should look on every device, and it should always be taken into consideration when developing a game with this tool.  It really should be the first thing that gets discussed so that people can understand the power behind it.

The only time I would recommend using `init(size:)` is when you need to create a dynamic scene that cannot be achieved via the sprite kit builder, and when you already have a static size of the window established.

Comment: Very good point. In my question I mentioned how using `init(size:)` instead of `init(fileNamed:)` results in the coordinates for one of my sprites getting messed up... the reason could very well be due to the danger of conflicting coordinates that you mentioned. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah,  that issue you listed could be any number of things.  I always recommend using the scene file (sks) and having the scene a square size,  this way you can develop for all aspect ratios and let the system do your cropping.  You need to do math to handle an overlay of course,  but this math is only done once saving you a ton of time.